# not passing values to repository class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i was creating a simple rest service in asp.net mvc.my problem is my value is not passing to `respository` class. i think i miss something can anyone help..?
here is my `controller`

```
static LoginRespository repository = new LoginRespository();
    public string AddEmployees(Login Emp)
    {
       //calling EmpRepository Class Method and storing Repsonse 
        var response = repository.AddEmployees(Emp);
        return response;

    }
```

and my `respository`class like this

```
 public string AddEmployees(Login Emp)
    {

        SqlCommand com;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DOTNET;Initial Catalog=edin;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        try
        {
            com = new SqlCommand("select * from data where name='" + Emp.username + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                return "success";
            }
            else
            {
                return "error";
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception aa)
        {
            return aa.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and my `model`is

```
public string username { get; set; }
public string password { get; set; }
```

Comment: how to do  you use your controller? Can you show how you pass value to the controller?

Comment: ` var response = repository.AddEmployees(Emp);`//calling EmpRepository Class Method and storing Repsonse

Comment: sorry i mean. how do you call the controller on client side? Are you sure that there is a value on (Emp)?

Comment: @Edison there is a missing part, the binding of your model from the client sent values

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to:

- In method AddEmployees instead of passing collection of Employees you pass single employee and suggest change to AddEmployee
- Instead of Insert you add Employee with Select
- If you receive null Employee in AddEmployee that means that you send null Employee in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you calling the AddEmployees on button click event. Try this:

```
Emp employeeRec = new Emp();
employeeRec.username = txtName.text;
employeeRec.password = txtPassword.text;

AddEmployees(employeeRec);
```